# How to clean jms queue from spring jms?

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

How to clean jms queue from spring jms? Like "clean" command from MQ Explorer? Or I should recieve messages until them end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot issue a clean command easily from JMS, since that requires the full MQI api. As you say, a good way is to read all messages one by one and discard them. You even get the choice to do this when clearing a queue in MQ explorer as well